# working remotely on Lenovo ThinkCenter M900 - shutting down and starting up issues

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have to work remotely on a Lenovo ThinkCentre M900 machine (from now on dubbed as the PC; win 10 x64 pro, build17134.345, version1803).

- If I'm starting the PC without the Display port cable (connected to a monitor), the Windows 10 doesn't start - I'm trying to connect remotely to it but it shows the following
  [image]
- If I'm connecting the cable and restart the PC, the windows starts and I can remote connect to this PC
- If (while remote connected) I shutdown the PC (from the start menu), it enters in state in which I have to shut it down manually

Can these issues be fixed?

- I mean, I would like to remote connect to this PC even if (I start this PC and) it doesn't have a monitor (via Display Port) - I prefer using the monitor to another computer.
- I would like to close the PC via Remote Desktop without entering in any weird state and have it to shut it down (again) manually (clicking the button from the PC case)

**Update:** the PC uses the integrated graphics card

Thank you!
R

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite complex because I don't really see the relationship between the monitor and the fact that you can't work remotely. Personally I would recommend you to check the network connection between your server and the machine you want to connect to remotely.
and if your computer won't boot without the display cable, trying to connect remotely is already a waste of time.

Comment: the connection between the machines is ok (as I mentioned, only if I plugin the monitor to the PC, and then start the PC, I can connect to it - so it's working somehow). I'm not proficient in networks _et_ _al._ but the machines I'm using have almost the same IPs (10.5.10. _x_, where _x_ is different for each machine)
Please give me some hints what other information (regarding networks) I can add to the question so that you/or others could/might help me. thanks

Comment: Have you tried entering the bios settings to see the default set configurations? Here I speak for the case of the machine that does not start without a display monitor.

Comment: Yes, I did.
- I saw that the video is set to Auto (BIOS > Devices > Video setup > Select active video (available options: IGD, PEG and Auto)) - but I have no clue what they do.
- I've also disabled "C1E support" (BIOS > Advanced > CPU setup > C1E support)  (I thought it allows entering in that funny/weird state after shuting down -but it doesn't help)

Comment: in the bios settings, there might be a toggle halt: on all errors, on major errors, on no errors see if such a setting exists, and put it on "halt on no errors". take a look, if the're is something like that it may solve the issue.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I'd been looking through the BIOS options, but I hadn't identified any useful toggle halt option. (I have something called Error Boot Sequence, but it only contains some devices like the SATA1/2/3/4, Network1: IBA CL Slot 00fe v0109, M.2 NVME/Sata; another thing called Configuration Change detection is disable, meaning any hardware changes will be not announced during booting).

Comment: I've also experimented with the Devices > VideoSetup triying to force the PC to use the IntegratedGraphicsDevice (my pc has an integrated graphics card - no PCI-Expres video card) and not looking for something else, but it didnt't help